# How do you model acoustic waves underwater that are generated by an Nd:YAG laser?

Tags: sound, wave, pressure, acoustic-noise

In [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c10f/3e4c6add95f1163dad57f78f4d323fb3f4c0.pdf) on page 84 they show the following experimental setup:

[image]

The array of receiver [hydrophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophone) are set up to record sound pressure waves sent by the transmitter hydrophones.

In Figure 6.13 on page 87 shown below, you can see the relative sound pressure decreases with increasing relative distance.

[image]

I would like to essentially duplicate this experiment with one difference : use an [Nd:YAG laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nd:YAG_laser) to focus a beam at a single point on the water surface to form a plasma under water.  This laser would be 20 ft above the surface of water and some arbitrary angle from the normal vector to the water surface.

This plasma will undergo [thermal expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion).  This expansion will then generate sound pressure (or acoustic) waves that the hydrophones can detect.

Two questions:

1. Does it make sense for me to use the exact same hydrophones they use in the paper (i.e. now that I am using laser pulse to generate underwater sound pressure waves, how do I decide the best hydrophone to use?)
2. Before purchasing a hydrophone, is there a way I can simulate this experiment to get a better idea of what I need? For example, how do you model a laser beam focused at a point on the water surface that forms plasma underwater? And separately, given a particular plasma shape, how do you model the sound pressure wave that gets generated?

Obviously I don't expect complete answers to my questions, but if somebody could even point me to other papers that might have answers, then I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This might be better suited for the physics StackExchange.

Comment: Photoacoustic imaging (using an array of hydrophones to image the sound waves generated by an optical excitation in tissue or other fluid) is a large area of research with numerous books written on the topic.  I'm not an expert, but this is something you can probably find at a library.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Photoacoustic+imaging&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk012uCmsVnnx43vIG3MfsH8SHB2_Jw:1588810688815&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=McyRbVaulh1hEM%253A%252CyjscELBxjeTqvM%252C%252Fm%252F08mt9s&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kT7NugH7W8CVkvd9TG47oTVto3YmA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw9-KFvaDpAhXHXc0KHXZlBdsQ_B0wO3oECAUQAw#imgrc=pcs9u_PDsKDaEM

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Photoacoustic+imaging&tbm=isch&chips=q:photoacoustic+imaging,g_1:sensor&client=firefox-b-d&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwiN4YOCvqDpAhXDds0KHTdUD4wQ4lYoEHoECAEQJQ&biw=1903&bih=949